# Regex Reverse Search on a String

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract the second last value in a string so I can return the value "**Minute**". I'm using Zapier which only allows regex.

**Example string:**

```
Week,Day,Hour,Another,Hour,Minute,Second
```

I've got a positive lookahead working below that returns the value "Second", however I cannot figure out how to apply an n-1 style operator to return the second-last string value "**Minute**".

**My regex:**

```
(?!^\,)[^,]*$
```

Try it here: https://regex101.com/r/mXVg6W/1

Any ideas?

Comment: In what cases the tags `regex-lookarounds` and `regex-groups` should be specifically used? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @lemon When the question is specific about these constructs. Here, no capturing groups are in question. Lookarounds are not the focus point here either, it is used, but OP just used it as a guess, without understanding what they are doing. The only problem is regex in general here, just the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
[^,]+(?=(?:,[^,]+){1}$)
```

It extracts the first non-comma values `[^,]+` occurring after a comma, a sequence of non-comma values and the end of string `(?:,[^,]+){1}$`. If you want preceeding values, it's sufficient to increment the value inside of the braces (the amount of `,string` to be passed over).

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/S3Vtpf/1).

Comment: This works very neatly, thanks! If I wanted to adjust which position I extracted the string from, say to return "Hour" or "Another", could your regex be manipulated to do that?

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

How about letting the dot [consume](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2301291/5527985) and [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (no lookarounds).

```
.*,([^,]+),
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Hv5YnQ/1)

Obviously this only makes if at lesat two commas occure in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? `[\d+\,]{9}(\d)[\,\d]`

Comment: `\d` matches a digit.